# How to print account transactions for a time period in GNUCash?

Tags: bank-account, gnucash, annual-report

I would like to print all the transactions for an account from, for example, 01/01/2015 to 31/12/2015. I found the report in `Reports > Account Reports` but that displays all the transactions in the account since its creation, and I couldn't find a way to set a time interval.

Is there any way to do this in GnuCash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stemic put me in the right direction, but the report that worked for me is "General Ledger". From there, by going into Options, it's possible to select the account and time period.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the report Assets & Liabilities -> General Journal or Income & Expense -> Cashflow. You can for both choose the report period by going into "Options", which is available when viewing the report (i.e. after creating the report). Note that in these options you will also have to select the GnuCash account that corresponds to your bankaccount.

Comment: Thank you, however I've tried General Journal and it didn't have an option to select an account or a date interval, however "General Ledger" did. Maybe this is what you meant, at it least it does the job for me.